# What is the Level of Evidence of "simultaneous self-controlled study"?

Tags: experiment-design, control-group

I guess this is an undefined thing, and would like to know your opinion. What is the Level of Evidence (as defined in the link by Oxford https://www.cebm.net/2009/06/oxford-centre-evidence-based-medicine-levels-evidence-march-2009/) of a study which is (a) a prospective therapeutic study, (b) using consecutive patients, and (c) self-controlled in a SIMULTANEOUS fashion (that is, "intervene" the left hand but leave the right hand intact). Both hands are, based on clinical knowledge, identical in this setting and, therefore, no randomization is involved in this study. Both "patients" and physicians know that the left hand is the hand to be "intervened". 
Please note that this study is NOT a before-and-after self-controlled study, which is frequently reported in the internal medicine field. If you could also provide a reference supporting your opinion, that would be even greater!

Comment: I think there are several competing ideas of level of evidence. Could you cite the levels-of-evidence scheme you have in mind? Also, is the treated eye assigned randomly, or determined in some other way? Also, does the patient or practitioner know which eye is being treated? Edit your question to clarify these details.

Comment: Hi Kodiologist, thank you so much for your reminder and editing, I have revised my question accordingly and I hope it now becomes more worthy of asking. Thanks again!

Comment: So *all* the patients are treated on their left eye (or hand, or whatever organ it is)?

Comment: Yes @Kodiologist, what is your opinion please:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CEBM levels are coarse in that they provide no intermediate ground between a randomized controlled trial (1b) and a cohort study (2b, which I understand to mean a study that has a longitudinal design but involves no experimental manipulation at all). Your study involves a treatment, but there are no control patients, just control hands, and the treated hand is always the left hand rather than being randomly assigned. So, the study provides weaker causal evidence than an RCT, but stronger causal evidence than a cohort study. I'd call it 1.5b.